# What does the Loyalty Across Lifetimes trait do?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I've started playing an Unchained Summoner with my play group, and I'm trying to round out the last little bits of by character. When I was looking through traits, I saw [Faith trait Loyalty across Lifetimes](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCampaign/characterBackground/traits.html), which reads:

> You and your eidolon share a link that seems to span multiple lifetimes. Your eidolon treats its Constitution score as if it were 2 points higher for the purposes of determining when its negative hit point total sends it back to its home plane. In addition, your eidolon gains a +1 trait bonus on Will saves against enchantment spells and effects.

I don't think this means that the Eidolon gains a permanent +2 to Con, but I'm not sure how to interpret this trait. What does it actually do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It lets your eidolon stick around at ever-so-slightly lower negative hit point values.**

From the [PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/summoner-unchained):

> ... An eidolon is treated as a summoned creature, except it is not sent back to its home plane until reduced to a number of negative hit points equal to or greater than its Constitution score. ...

The Loyalty Across Lifetimes trait makes your eidolon's Constitution score count as 2 points higher for that specific rule. So if your eidolon had a Constitution of 12, it would return to its home plane when reduced to -14 hit points, rather than when reduced to -12 hit points. Which is, honestly, not a very impressive benefit.

Comment: So to clarify, this means the Eidolon would stay unconscious for an additional two turns (assume no additional interference) before being sent back to its home plane?

Comment: @SocioMatt If the eidolon is in the dying state then yes, you would have an additional 2 turns to stabilize it.

Answer (score 2):

Your Eidolon is normally sent back to its home plane if it's reduced to negative hit points equal to or greater than its Constitution score. This trait increases the amount of negative hit points before it is sent back by 2.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, your Eidolon does not gain a permanent +2 to Con.

First, let's check what the normal rules for Eidolons are.  From the [PRD](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedPlayersGuide/baseClasses/summoner.html#eidolon):

> Eidolons are treated as summoned creatures, except that they are not sent back to their home plane until reduced to a number of negative hit points equal to or greater than their Constitution score.

So this trait gives your Eidolon the ability to take two extra damage before being forcibly unsummoned.